# nonlinear differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

For such a equation

$$-y''(x) + x^2\cdot y(x) - |y(x)|^2\cdot y(x) = 0$$

with initial conditions: $y(-500) = 0$ and $y(500) = 0$.

I write in mathematica

```
ic1 = 0;
xmax = 500;
xmin = -500;
sol = NDSolve[{-y''[x] + x^2*y[x] - Abs[y[x]]^2*y[x] == 0, 
   y[xmax] == ic1, y[xmin] == ic1}, y[x], {x, xmin, xmax}]
Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, xmin, xmax}]
```

but the graph is incorrect. Please help me

Comment: Can you show the output? It produces a straight zero line for me.

Comment: as far as i know, straight zero line is incorrect for this differential equation

Comment: Well, you can see pretty easily that y(x)=0 is a solution to the DE and the boundary conditions.

Comment: ok, let me correct my expression it is mistake to say incorrect, but are you saying it has only trivial solution ?

Comment: Is this just a clarification of [your earlier question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84246/nonlinear-schrödinger-equation-eigenvalues)?  If so, you should just edit the previous question and delete this one.

Comment: Solving for `y[x]`, we can see that there is only one real root. (`Solve[-y''[x] + x^2*y[x] - Abs[y[x]]^2*y[x] == 0, y[x]]`). Moreover, your conditions suggestion that, there will be only trivial solution to this problem. Please paste a link, where we can see the equation ourselves.

Comment: If you drop the non linear terms you get the Schrödinger equation for the harmonic oscillator but with a "forced eigenvalue" zero. This leaves only the trivial solution

Comment: It would be interesting to solve an eigenvalue problem for the nunlinear equation. But to this end you need to add a term like w*y [x] where w is the eigenvalue. Also I suggest to introduce a factor a before the nunlinear term. You could then study the shifting of the oscillator eigenvaluesas a function of a.

Comment: I have no access to mma, otherwise I would have started. But I'm also pretty sure that this problem has been studied a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the ode under discussion has only trivial solution.

I checked it with both Mathematica and maple and got what was expected.

**Mathematica output**

```
Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, xmin, xmax}]
```

[image]

**Maple output**

```
restart:with(plots):
```

`ode:=-diff(y(x),x$2)+x^2*y(x)-abs(y(x))^2*y(x)=0;`

`ics:=y(-500)=0,y(500)=0;`

`p:=dsolve({ode,ics},numeric);`

`odeplot(p);`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all reply....@ Dr. Wolfgang Hintze yes i am searching for its eigenvalue problem as an exercise either, as you mentioned, with added the term like E*y(x) where E is eigenvalue, Do you have any idea?